# Where Linux ping command gets its id counter?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ping

I noticed that `ping` ([iputils](https://github.com/iputils/iputils)) increases ICMP `id` counter every time it's being executed. I tried looking at the [ping source code](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/tree/master/ping) at quick glance but didn't find the counter. AFAIK ping doesn't run any daemon(s) or other system global state so is the Linux kernel itself keeping a record of this counter?

```
% ping -c 3 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
```

Tshark (id=0x0043):

```
14267 196372.989831489    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0043, seq=1/256, ttl=64
14268 196372.989843064    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0043, seq=1/256, ttl=64 (request in 14267)
14269 196374.001333266    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0043, seq=2/512, ttl=64
14270 196374.001345051    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0043, seq=2/512, ttl=64 (request in 14269)
14271 196375.014707417    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0043, seq=3/768, ttl=64
14272 196375.014717838    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0043, seq=3/768, ttl=64 (request in 14271)
```

Ping again:

```
% ping -c 3 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
```

Tshark (id=0x0044):

```
14273 196381.959906106    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0044, seq=1/256, ttl=64
14274 196381.959921324    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0044, seq=1/256, ttl=64 (request in 14273)
14275 196382.961393309    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0044, seq=2/512, ttl=64
14276 196382.961404803    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0044, seq=2/512, ttl=64 (request in 14275)
14277 196383.974709944    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0044, seq=3/768, ttl=64
14278 196383.974722217    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0044, seq=3/768, ttl=64 (request in 14277)
```

Comment: It's [here](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/b6a5bc35620cc2c23709a00e3db3bb89709a694b/ping/ping.c#L1446)

Comment: @user414777 That seems to be the sequence number, not id? It might be this one - https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/b6a5bc35620cc2c23709a00e3db3bb89709a694b/ping/ping.c#L1701

Comment: If it's across runs, then guess: As ping cannot keep track of state between different runs, I'd assume it's the OS the increases the id counter as a side-effect of something ping does, and not ping itself.

Comment: Rather https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping/ping_common.c#L525

Comment: my bad, sorry for misreading your q